# Postgres: Combine update queries to one query on hierarchic table

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a hierarchic table where each row contains an id of various parents. updating a row (set it as active) means that i have to update every parent of this row. how can i combine these queries into one query?  currently i use this solution which is not very nice. i guess this can be done with a recursive CTE, but i can't figure out the right way here. thanks in advance!

```
update areas set active = true  where id = 1000;
update areas set active = true  where id = (select parent1 from areas where id = 1000);
update areas set active = true  where id = (select parent2 from areas where id = 1000);
update areas set active = true  where id = (select parent3 from areas where id = 1000);
update areas set active = true  where id = (select parent4 from areas where id = 1000);
```

Comment: Your method is fine, actually.  You can wrap it in a single transaction if you like.

Comment: Why do you have 4 parent columns in your table?

Comment: i need to have various parent columns to get a specific parent without extra costs, e.g. self-joins or a recursive query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're saying set active = true if it's either the node itself, parent1, parent2, parent3 or parent4, which are all present when you query the node by id. So putting them together in an array is all you need.

```sql
UPDATE
  areas
SET
  active = True
WHERE
  id = ANY(
    SELECT
      UNNEST(ARRAY[id, parent1, parent2, parent3, parent4])
    FROM
      areas
    WHERE
      id = 1000
  )
```

Comment: thanks, this is quiet close, i just had to use a wrapping "unnest", because ANY does not work with a subselect: -> operator does not exist: numeric = numeric[]